# Dictionary if Key exist append if not add new element C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I am having

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>> filters = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
```

which is having values like `country = us`. till now I am able to add it when key is not repeated. now when key `country` is repeated. it is showing that the key is already present.

what I want is How to add multiple values in the same key. I am not able to do it. Please suggest something.

```
for (int i = 0; i < msgProperty.Value.Count; i++)
{
    FilterValue.Add(msgProperty.Value[i].filterValue.Value);
    filterColumn = msgProperty.Value[i].filterColumnName.Value;
    filters.Add(filterColumn, FilterValue);
}
```

what I want

> country = US,UK

Comment: consider using `Lookup` instead of a `Dictionary`

Comment: @w.b with List<keyvaluePair<string,List<string>> ?

Comment: `Lookup<string, string>`

Comment: The intend is not clear, so I wouldn't recommend `Lookup`. You can't add additional values to the object (its a one-time create, read-many object).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The different types of all your variables are a bit confusing, which won't help you writing the code. I'm assuming you have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the key is a "language" and the value is a list of countries for that language, or whatever. Reducing a problem to a minimal set that reproduces the issue is very helpful when asking for help.

Anyway assuming the above, it's as simple as this:

- Try to get the `dictionary["somelanguage"]` key into `existingValue`.
- If it doesn't exist, add it and store it in the same variable.
- Add the `List<string>` to the dictionary under the "somelanguage" key.

The code will look like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary;

void AddCountries(string languageKey, List<string> coutriesToAdd)
{
    List<string> existingValue = null;

    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(languageKey, out existingValue))
    {
        // Create if not exists in dictionary
        existingValue = dictionary[languageKey] = new List<string>()
    }

    existingValue.AddRange(coutriesToAdd);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to check whether the value exists in the dictionary, like this:

```
if (!filters.ContainsKey("country"))
      filters["country"] = new List<string>();

filters["country"].AddRange("your value");
```

Comment: it is overwriting the old value

Comment: you need to create a comma separated value before inserting a new value to the "country" key

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to add value for key country

```
List<string> existingValues;
if (filters.TryGetValue(country, out existingValues))
    existingValues.Add(value);
else
  filters.Add(country, new List<string> { value })
```

If your values is `List<string>`

```
List<string> existingValues;
if (filters.TryGetValue(country, out existingValues))
    existingValues.AddRange(values);
else
    filters.Add(country, new List<string> { values })
```

Comment: This contains a double lookup, its better to use `TryGetValue` instead.

Comment: The Value-Type of the dictionary is `List<string>`. Your code would not work.

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande is your value a List<string> ?

Comment: @ArghyaC yes list<String> thats the problem

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [IDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) interface.

```
IDictionary dict = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();


if (!dict.ContainsKey("key"))
      dict["key"] = new List<string>();

filters["key"].Add("value");
```